# Engine and gearbox replacement for 1993 Mitsubishi Triton 4x4

Tags: engine, 4wd, mitsubishi

I'm sure it's possible technically but I would like to know what the options are for engine replacements. The 4 cyl engine in my Ute is past its life expectancy. I'm interested to know if a new modern engine could be fitted and if so which one? Failing that would it be possible to replace the 4 cyl engine with the 6 cyl engine that they also put in some versions of this truck?
I know it is probably better to just buy a newer truck but I've done a lot of custom work on this truck and if possible I'd prefer to keep it and put in a more reliable engine.

The current engine is a 4G54.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with spending time and money to do interesting things to old vehicles.

I'm guessing you have the model with the 4g64 engine?  If so, why not do another 4g64?  It's still being used on modern vehicles, you may not have too much work to do to fit a current generation 4g64 into your old vehicle.  Might be a difference in crank/cam angle sensor and possibly knock sensors, but since the 4g64 is a popular base for building race engines for a few platforms, conversion parts are available to make the signals compatible.

Comment: Thanks. I was out earlier but I have checked and the current engine is a 4g54

Comment: Oh, that's a pretty good engine there too!  I'd just rebuild and maybe upgrade it some!  :-)

Comment: Okay thanks. Good to know it's a reasonable engine. I will investigate getting a rebuild done. :)